# How would I approach training a model and encoding this categorical data

Tags: machine-learning, regression, categorical-data, encoding

So I have the following data:
I have one series where each word has a value that describes the average review score that would get.
For example, if the word "excellent" showed up in reviews with a score of 2,3,5,4 it would gain a value of 3.5.

I also have a list of the words contained in a review, and the review scores of each of those written reviews.
For example,

```
Unique_words
["good","clean","hotel","enjoyed","stay","here"]

score
4
```

(These are ofc simplified examples, my actual data is a lot longer)

I also have the original reviews, from which the unique_words are taken from.

The question is, how would I use this data in order to train a machine-learning algorithm to predict what score a review would get, given the unique words contained inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode categorical variables as dummies.

This means to create new features for each type of category and then assigned either a 1 (where a record has that category) or 0 (to each record that doesn't have that category). With some examples, this should look something like this

```
                        good  clean  hotel  enjoyed  stay  here
I am good               1     0      0      0        0     0
My face is clean        0     1      0      0        0     0
This is a clean hotel   0     1      1      0        0     0
I enjoyed a good meal   1     0      0      1        0     0
Don't stay here         0     0      0      0        1     0
```

In python you can use the pandas function `pd.get_dummies()`

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there would be a way to avoid this. Since I've got more than 50k unique words that I've assigned the value to, creating a new feature for each word makes the DataFrame really big and slow to run through.

Also side question; is there a way (or even a benefit) to keep count of how many times a certain word shows up in the review. One could assume that a review that has the word  `bad` five times is lower than one that mentions it once.

Comment: I don't know of any other way but make sure you are using sparse matrices. Also, take a look at tfidf which weights things based on how often they occur.